# Origem histórica de "calça"

Tags: origem-histórica

No outra dúvida sobre vestir, calçar e usar. Surgiu uma dúvida..

Entendo a origem da [calça](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cal%C3%A7a) (que significa sapato ou meia em latim), mas em que momento a palavra virou calça de vestir?

Achei [esta resposta](https://pt.quora.com/Por-que-respectivamente-cal%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-calcinha-s%C3%A3o-aumentativo-e-diminutivo-da-palavra-cal%C3%A7a-Qual-%C3%A9-a-origem-disso) em outro site relacionado com calcinhas, mas falta o momento da transição.

Answer (score 3):

Eis a explicação dada pelo Houasiss:

> Latim vulgar *calcea, derivado de calcĕus no sentido de 'calçado, sapato'; antes significava 'meia', pois os romanos, que não usavam nem meias nem calças, aprenderam com os germanos, que habitavam um clima frio, o uso dessas peças de vestuário e as designaram com a palavra usada para sapato; com o passar dos tempos, as calças foram encompridando até cobrir o corpo, dos pés à cintura; no século XVI, as calças se dividiram em duas partes: a que cobria a barriga e as coxas manteve o mesmo nome (calças ou calça) e a que cobria as pernas e o pé ficou sendo chamada de meia calça, depois meia, com a elipse de calça.